# Pausing or muting music when someone speaks on a Zoom call

Tags: audio

I'm often in "open" zoom calls for work where people are quiet for long periods and will then start talking. I usually listen to music in the silence but need to be very quick with the pause hotkey.

I'm trying to automate this where Spotify audio is paused (or muted) when someone is speaking on Zoom. I have Sound Source installed as a mixer and I saw the same company makes [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/), but I didn't see a way to trigger something based on the volume application of an app.

Is there any app that does this?

Comment: The term is *muted*. It means to suppress sound.  *Deafened* means unable to *hear* sound.  You *mute* Spotify, you deafen your ears.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure what the word was when it's not fully mute but like 80% mute (like ios will do for music if another app is making noise, like a call).